# How can I calculate an average value of specific inductor current?

Tags: current, inductor, rms

There is a inductance current signal in below. I want to calculate the average value of the current.

Possitive peak value is 33.4 A 
Negative peak value is -20 A

Peak to peak time is 36 µs. But I do not know how can I calculate it in the shortest way.

[image]

Comment: The graph is from a simulator so, use the simulator to tell you what it is.

Comment: I know it Sir :) But ı need a mathematical formula to make an excel for my design book.

Comment: Excel has an average function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given some periodic current function \$I(t)\$, with period \$T\$, the formula for its average \$I_{MEAN}\$ is:

$$ I_{MEAN} = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T{I \cdot dt } $$

Presumably you have a sequence of samples \$I_0\cdots I_{N-1}\$ of this waveform, where \$N\$ is the number of samples in a single period. That is, you have \$N\$ samples of current \$I\$ describing exactly one complete cycle. The discrete version of the above equation is:

$$ I_{MEAN} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{a=0}^{N-1}{ I_a } $$

In plain English, this means add up all the samples, and divide by \$N\$.